# GIT push error - expected committer email 'user@xyz.com ' but found 'user@xyz.com'

Tags: git, git-push

I am new to GIT and trying my first ever push. Iam getting the below error.

```
Error:
expected committer email 'user@xyz.com ' but found 'user@xyz.com'
[remote rejected] ...(pre-receive hook declined)
```

As you can see, expected and actual email is same except the extra tailing white-space in expected committer email.

I want to understand where the "expected committer email" value is being picked up from. Is it from git server account? or something that can be changed locally?

Tried setting user.email using below commands, but still facing same issue.

```
git config --global user.email "user@xyz.com"
git commit --amend --reset-author


git config --global user.email "user@xyz.com"
git commit --amend --allow-empty --author="user, user <user@xyz.com>"
```

Comment: It would help if you told us more about your remote host. Is it bitbucket/github/gitlab or a private server? It seems like your remote host is expecting a wrong email (with a space in it).

Comment: We use stash and it is a private server

Comment: Your private server is misconfigured. It's performing some kind of check on commits, but doing it incorrectly: your commits have your correct email address and it's demanding that they have an incorrect email address. The right fix is to fix the server; the workaround is to use an incorrect email address.

Comment: The apparent culprit is you pre-receive hook. The script may need to be fixed

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the issue was with the server configuration. There were extra spaces in the values configured on server.
Worked fine after fixing the server side values.